# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException while sending push notification using either APNS or JavaAPNS

Tags: java, exception, ssl, apple-push-notifications, sslhandshakeexception

Working on a Java server application, which would send the Apple push notification to the user.

Working from last few days to resolve SSL handshake issue, getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake" when my Java server application tries to send APNS message

Tried with two separate libraries APNS(https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns_ and Java-APNS(https://code.google.com/p/javapns/) but getting the same issue in both cases

Here is my APNS sample code

```
@Service(value = "apnsPushService")
public class APNSPushService extends AbstractPushService    {

    protected String certificate = null;
    protected String passphrase = null;
    private ApnsService service = null;

    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
    super.init();
    try {
        service = buildApnsService();
        service.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("While building the APNS service", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean pushMessage(String notificationKey, String message) throws Exception {
    PayloadBuilder builder = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(alert) // alert dialog, in iOS
        .badge(badge) // little badge icon update;
        .sound(sound); // sound to be played by app

    builder = builder.alertBody(message);

    final String apnsMessage = builder.build(); // build the JSON payload for APNs
    logger.info("Sending transformed APNs payload: " + apnsMessage);

    service.push(notificationKey, apnsMessage, createFutureDateBasedOnTTL(timeToLive));
    return true;
}

/**
* Helper method that creates a future {@link Date}, based on the given ttl/time-to-live value. If no TTL was provided, we use the max date from
* the APNs library
*/
private Date createFutureDateBasedOnTTL(int ttl) {

    // no TTL was specified on the payload, we use the MAX Default from the
    // APNs library:
    if (ttl == -1) {
        return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EnhancedApnsNotification.MAXIMUM_EXPIRY * 1000L);
    } else {
        // apply the given TTL to the current time
        return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + ttl);
    }
}

/**
* Build the APNS Service
* 
* @return
*/
private ApnsService buildApnsService() throws Exception {
    ApnsService apnsService = null;
    // this check should not be needed, but you never know:
    if (certificate != null && passphrase != null) {

        final ApnsServiceBuilder builder = APNS.newService();
        try(InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(certificate)) {
            builder.withCert(stream, passphrase);

            // pick the destination:
            if (production) {
                builder.withProductionDestination();
            } else {
                builder.withSandboxDestination();
            }
        }

        // create the service
        return builder.build();
    }

    return apnsService;
}

@Value("${apns.certificate}")
public void setCertificate(String certificate) {
    this.certificate = certificate;
}

@Value("${apns.passphrase}")
public void setPassphrase(String passphrase) {
    this.passphrase = passphrase;
}

@Value("${apns.production}")
public void setProduction(String production) {
    this.production = Boolean.parseBoolean(production);
}

@Value("${apns.alert}")
public void setAlert(String alert) {
    this.alert = alert;
}

@Value("${apns.sound}")
public void setSound(String sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
}

@Value("${apns.badge}")
public void setBadge(String badge) {
    this.badge = Integer.parseInt(badge);
}

@Value("${apns.timetolive}")
public void setTimeToLive(String timeToLive) {
    this.timeToLive = Integer.parseInt(timeToLive);
}
}
```

Here is my Java APNS code -

```
public class JavaAPNSPushService extends AbstractPushService {

protected String certificate = null;
protected String passphrase = null;

private PushQueue queue = null;

private int counter = 1;

@Override
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
super.init();
queue= Push.queue(certificate, passphrase, production, 10);
queue.start();

}

@Override
public boolean pushMessage(String notificationKey, String message) throws Exception 
{
    if (counter++ > 1000) {
        counter = 1;
        queue.clearPushedNotifications();
    }

    PushNotificationPayload payload = new PushNotificationPayload(alert, badge, sound);
    payload.addAlert(message);
    payload.setExpiry(timeToLive);

    PushQueue tempQueue = queue.add(payload, notificationKey);

    List<Exception> expList = tempQueue.getCriticalExceptions();
    if (expList.size() > 0) {
        expList.get(0).printStackTrace();
    }

    PushedNotification notification =      tempQueue.getPushedNotifications().firstElement();
    while(!notification.isTransmissionCompleted()) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    return notification.isSuccessful();
}

    @Value("${apns.certificate}")
    public void setCertificate(String certificate) {
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    @Value("${apns.passphrase}")
    public void setPassphrase(String passphrase) {
        this.passphrase = passphrase;
    }

    @Value("${apns.production}")
    public void setProduction(String production) {
        this.production = Boolean.parseBoolean(production);
    }

    @Value("${apns.alert}")
    public void setAlert(String alert) {
        this.alert = alert;
    }

    @Value("${apns.sound}")
    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Value("${apns.badge}")
    public void setBadge(String badge) {
        this.badge = Integer.parseInt(badge);
    }

    @Value("${apns.timetolive}")
    public void setTimeToLive(String timeToLive) {
        this.timeToLive = Integer.parseInt(timeToLive);
    }

}
```

Here is my exception stack trace -

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:402)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:350)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:320)
    at javapns.Push.sendPayload(Push.java:177)
    at javapns.Push.test(Push.java:132)
    at com.aaplab.konvx.push.apns.JavaAPNSPushService.pushMessage(JavaAPNSPushService.java:69)
    at com.aaplab.konvx.push.AbstractPushService.push(AbstractPushService.java:61)
    at com.aaplab.konvx.PushTest.JavaAPNSPushTest(PushTest.java:36)
    at com.aaplab.konvx.PushTest.main(PushTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    ... 13 more
```

Have already followed various suggestions like:

1. Created .p12 certificate file  from private key and the cert download from Apple.Repeated multiple times but no luck.
2. Made sure that the certification is of development mode and not from production mode.
3. Even tried with a sample code which trusts all the certificates, still getting the same issue.

Although I am successfully able to telnet on "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"/2195 but when it comes to from java code things are not working.

Its certainly not proxy issue, as I have tested it from my windows machine as well as from our production server, failing at both side.

Not sending the message in bulk, just tried sending single message and it's failing.

Comment: try with Urbanairship push http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar, were you able to resolve this problem? I am also facing a similar problem.

Comment: @eshaa - yes resolved now, finally came to know that we were using a bad certificate - after applying a new certificate problem resolved.